# TypeScript changes do not reflect on browser

Tags: jhipster

I have created a Jhispter application with Angular and Java Spring Boot. I have made changes to Angular code which do not reflect when entire application is built.

`npm start` - builds the application on http://localhost:9000/ but when I do mvnw - it runs on http://localhost:8080/ which does not reflect the UI changes. tried installing packages and giving webpack build.

Show the changes on http://localhost:8080/ for testing the UI integration with Java.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, this works as documented in https://www.jhipster.tech/development/

Comment: Changes reflect on local host 9000 but for testing the integration with api calls, also for debugging the back-end calls need those changes to reflect in with java. For that I am doing `mvnw clean` and the `mvnw -Pdev, webpack`.

Answer (score 2):

To use Webpack *hot module reload* and see your (front-end) changes without restarting the application has to access through http://localhost:9060/

Instead, http://localhost:9000/ is a proxy for http://localhost:9060/, which allows you to use BrowserSync to test multiple browsers simultaneously.

To see the changes in http://localhost:8080/ or any change in the server side you need to stop the application and restart it again with maven or gradle, whatever you use.

Comment: Just restarting the application does not help. Have do a entire web-pack rebuild.